# UPDATE record if present; else INSERT

Tags: mysql, insert-update

I want to update a record which may or may not be present in a table. If it is not present in the database then it will be inserted.

To prevent from select I am using `UPDATE` statement first and checking `affected_rows > 0` if not then I am inserting this record into the table.

I was wondering if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: which one is better replace or insert..on duplicate key?

Comment: They behave differently. They are not "better" or "worse," but different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

---

The difference between this and `REPLACE` (Femaref's answer) is that `REPLACE` will *delete* the old row and then *insert* a new row if a key is duplicated, while this will *update* the existing row.

Comment: What if database goes down during replace process?

Comment: @Jason Yes it will. As long as there is a duplicate key it will do `UPDATE`

Comment: I just checked it, I have to add unique index on column(s) in order to find duplicates. Is it OK if I do not use primary key?

Comment: @Jason It depends on how you determine whether or not two records are "duplicates." You can have two people called "John Smith" and they are not the same person.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Replace` instead of `Insert`.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html